# Library "tornado-es" problems with big input source

Tags: asynchronous, elasticsearch, tornado

I'm using the asynchronous library `tornado-es` and I've got a problem when I try to perform a `search` with a big search body for parameter **source**.

The following is the response from ES:

`<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.</body></html>`

I tried to use the library `elasticsearch` for Python instead and everything works fine.

Are there some differences between `tornado-es` and `elasticsearch` libraries querying an ES database?

Thanks in advance.